# Why aren't my Divs auto adjusting location?

Tags: jquery, css, tabs

Using JQuery,
I have a set of four tab that start off like this:

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab1" checked />
        <label for="tab1">Item One</label>
        <div id="tab-content1" class="tab-content">
            <p>Text Here </p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

On a desktop it looks as desired. But on mobile, when the screen is shrunk the other tabs collapse under (which they are supposed to), but the text inside the div doesn't auto adjust down. This leaves the other tabs behind the visible text.

Is there any way to fix this?

Thank you,

For the full code see this JSFiddle page:
https://jsfiddle.net/hesbwgsm/2/

Comment: why don't you go for bootstrap `tabs` [Bootstrap Tabs and Pills](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tabs_pills.asp)

Comment: are you free to arrange your markup other than you post? can you collect all tab-conten-divs in a another div? or you must use the code you post it?

Comment: @jonju I tried using Bootstrap (I use it throughout the rest of my site).
But stylistically I could never get it to look just right. I don't like the default color scheme and my attempts to change some of the colors, etc. came out less than desirable.

Comment: @MarouenMhiri I'm not sure exactly what your asking... but I can write it any way that works... this was just the first way I came across that gave the desired appearance

Comment: @Arges86 you mean changing the default color of bootstrap `tabs'? Well you can change it to what ever you want.

Answer (score 0):

bacause of `.tabs li`
in your css, `.tabs` `width: 75%`  but `li` which inside of `ul` you don't give it any width

> replace this with yours

```
.tabs li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 25%;
}
```